# How do I decrease my range in every loop when loop was executing in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have to decrease my range in every loop end. here is an example code:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if (array[0][5] == array[i][5]):
       array2.append(array[0])
       array3.append(array[i])
       
       array.remove(array[i])
       array.remove(array[0])
```

this throws an error that list index out of range so I tried to add i-=1 in every remove functions end but it doesn't fix it.

I couldnt fixed it so I tried to fix this problem in another way.

```
n = len(array) # maybe it could be len(array) -1 for the index problem but I also tried that it didnt work.
k = len(array)-1
for n in range(n, 0, -2):
    if (array[0][5] == array[n][5]):
       array2.append(array[0])
       array3.append(array[n])
       
       array[k] = array[n]
       array[k-1] = array[0]
       k -= 2
```

I thought that if I do that, I shouldn't compare the last 2 values after the loop but the error is the same error : list index out of range

Solving this problem with NOT starting loop from the end is my first priority.

I want to match 2 values from 2 different arrays when arrays 2's elements equals to each other and then I have to out them off from the list because when I match 2 values I don't need them anymore. But there is a problem right there which is when I remove the element from the list, I can not reach all the values in the list because of the iteration still during.

```
array1 = [0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,1],[0,3]
array2 = [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,3]
for i in range(len(array1)):
   for j in range(len(array2)):
      if(array1[i][1] == array2[j][1]):
         temp_arr2.append(array1[i])
         temp_arr1.append(array2[j])
         array1.remove(array1[i])
         array2.remove(array2[j])
```

Comment: What is `n`, and how is it related to `array`?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you could just explain what you're trying to do with array, array2, and array3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: n should be i, I just fixed it. ARRAY is an 2 dimensional array, array2 is some part of the ARRAY, array3 is also some part of the ARRAY and I want to compare values in ARRAY's elements because I want to seperate array 2 parts. This comparation allows me to find difference between 2 arrays so I append some kind of values to array2 and some similar  values to array3. But there is a problem right there. Problem is: if I find the similar values in the array, ı have to out them off. if I still put them inside the array after the comparation, can match another values that I dont want to.

Comment: @grismar I already tried that you have mentioned above just check it I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you may not be able to control the iteration of the variable `i` when using it in a `for` loop. Your instincts are good in attempting to modify `i` by 1 for each `remove()` call, and the missing piece of the puzzle is to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Here is code that does what your question asks using sample data for `array`:

```
        array = [
            [0,0,0,0,0,99],
            [1,0,0,0,0,33],
            [2,0,0,0,0,66],
            [3,0,0,0,0,99],
            [4,0,0,0,0,33],
            [5,0,0,0,0,66],
            [6,0,0,0,0,99],
            [7,0,0,0,0,33],
            [8,0,0,0,0,66],
            [9,0,0,0,0,99],
            [10,0,0,0,0,33]
        ]
        array2 = []
        array3 = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(array):
            if (array[0][5] == array[i][5]):
                array2.append(array[0])
                array3.append(array[i])

                array.remove(array[i])
                array.remove(array[0])
                i += 2
            i += 1
        print(f"array {array}")
        print(f"array2 {array2}")
        print(f"array3 {array3}")
```

Here is sample output:

```
array [[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33], [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99], [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33], [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66], [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99], [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33]]
array2 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66]]
array3 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66]]
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is an updated answer based on the updated question.

It seems as though the main concern is identifying and collecting lists contained in `array1` and `array2` that have matching values in a particular index. The end state of `array1` and `array2` does not matter.

With this in mind, I suggest the following approach which uses a Python `dict` to identifying matches more efficiently than nested for loops, and which will create the required lists of matches. Note that it will not modify the original lists (`array1` and `array2`).

```
        array1 = [[100,1],[100,2],[100,2],[100,2],[100,1],[100,3]]
        array2 = [[200,1],[200,1],[200,1],[200,2],[200,2],[200,3]]
        dict1 = {}
        for i in range(len(array1)):
            key = array1[i][1]
            if key not in dict1:
                dict1[key] = []
            dict1[key].append(i)
        temp_arr1 = []
        temp_arr2 = []
        for j in range(len(array2)):
            key = array2[j][1]
            if key in dict1:
                i = dict1[key][0]
                temp_arr2.append(array1[i])
                temp_arr1.append(array2[j])
                dict1.pop(key)
        print(temp_arr1)
        print(temp_arr2)
```

Here are the outputs:

```
[[200, 1], [200, 2], [200, 3]]
[[100, 1], [100, 2], [100, 3]]
```

As you can see, the first output row (`temp_arr1`) contains lists that were originally in `array2` and the second output row (`temp_arr2`) contains lists that were originally in `array1`. This matches the updated sample code in the question.

Comment: when you increase i by 2 in if statement, end of the if statement you are not able to access array's [0] and [1] indexes in another loop so you can not compare those indexes with others.

Comment: @maddog, that's true, and before I update my answer, let me ask: in your original code, when you write `array.remove(array[0])`, is it your intention that on the next loop iteration the `==` comparison will be made between the new `array[0]` (i.e., what was previously `array[1]`) and `array[i]`?

Comment: @maddog, another question to ensure I am fully understanding your goal: given the sample `array` in my answer, what is the desired end result for `array2` and `array3`?

Comment: in my original code, 3 more comparation that I need first if array[0][5] == array[i][5] second if array1[0][5] == array1[0][5] etc.  but these comparations not important at all. If I can handle with this >remove and compare> problem, its okay for me

Comment: I mentioned above before; ARRAY is an 2 dimensional array, array2 is some part of the ARRAY, array3 is also some part of the ARRAY and I want to compare values in ARRAY's elements because I want to seperate array 2 parts. This comparation allows me to find difference between 2 arrays so I append some kind of values to array2 and some similar values to array3. But there is a problem right there. Problem is: if I find the similar values in the array, ı have to out them off. if I still put them inside the array after the comparation, can match another values that I dont want to.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your exact goal. Can you give a concrete example please for `array` and for `array2` and `array3`? I think if you can provide that, I should then be able to refine my answer to do what you need.

Comment: I want to match 2 values from 2 different arrays when arrays 2's elements equals to each other and then I have to out them off from the list because when I match 2 values I don't need them anymore. But there is a problem right there which is when I remove the element from the list, I can not reach all the values in the list because of the iteration still during.

Comment: ```
temp_arr1 = []
temp_arr2 = []

array1 = [0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,1],[0,3]
array2 = [0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[0,3]
for i in range(len(array1)):
   for j in range(len(array2)):
      if(array1[i][1] == array2[j][1]):
         temp_arr2.append(array1[i])
         temp_arr1.append(array2[j])
         array1.remove(array1[i])
         array2.remove(array2[j])
```

Comment: take a look at it ı just edited again my question

Comment: OK, your new example is helpful. What would `array1` and `array2` look like after the loops have executed? For example, do you want them both to be empty (since both contain the same elements, just in different sequence and with a different number of copies)? Or, do you want `array1` to contain `[0,2]` (since it started with 3 copies and `array2` started with only 2 copies) and `array2` to contain `[0,1]` (since it started with 3 copies and `array1` started with only 2 copies)?

Comment: it doesn't matter what array1 and array2 looks like its should just be empty after the iteration because when I match 2 values ı dont need them anymore, I'm appending another 2 temp array and return them. I can concatenate them later so it doesn't matter. If they same values , first one will be added

Comment: Got it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @maddog Do you need any more help with this?